# Long polling PHP. Keep DB connection or not?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, long-polling, polling

I'm trying out long polling for the first time.

In the PHP script I have a while-loop with a sleep-timer that freezes the script for 10 seconds, then it looks for new stuff in the database again.

I'm thinking performance and server/database load/connections:

What is worse for the server: Many GET-requests (ajax), or many opening/closing of the DB connection?

Would it in any way be better to use long polling but close and re-open the DB connection in each round of the while-loop (to free the limited number of connections)?

Answer (score 0):

This is less trivial, than it sounds: What starts with a simple "should I or not" alternative rapidly increases in complexity with scaling to more servers.

Having hit walls with both approaches, we have come up with a proxy scheme, that seems to work well even on cheap shared hosting:

- Run a single instance of a simple proxy script, that polls the DB (On shared hosting we start this from a cron job, that starts an instance only, if no other is running, so we easily survive reboots)
- Have that proxy script translate the expensive DB poll into a cheaper poll: SysV SHM and flagfiles in the filesystem both work fine. The proxy should keep its single DB connection open
- Have your potentiallly many long-pollers check the proxied flag.

This has made it possible to implement a short server-sided polling intervall without running into problems, when concurrent polls increase.